# Not able to register UDF in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I trying to register my UDF function and want to use this in my spark sql query but not able to register my udf Im getting below error.

```
    val squared = (s: Column) => { 
    concat(substring(s,4,2),year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(s,"dd-MM-yyyy")))))
    }
    squared: org.apache.spark.sql.Column => org.apache.spark.sql.Column = <function1>

    scala> sqlContext.udf.register("dc",squared)
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Column is not   supported
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:733)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:671)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.register(UDFRegistration.scala:143)
    ... 48 elided
```

I tried to change Column to String but getting below error.

```
    val squared = (s: String) => { 
    | concat(substring(s,4,2),year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(s,"dd-MM-yyyy")))))
    | }
    <console>:28: error: type mismatch;
    found   : String
    required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
   concat(substring(s,4,2),year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(s,"dd-MM-yyyy")))))


   can someone please guide me how should i implement this.
```

Comment: AFAIK User defined UDFs can only have primitive datatypes arguments and return type as String,Long,Array,... but not Spark's Column

Answer (score 1):

All spark functions from this package org.apache.spark.sql.functions._  will not be able to access inside UDF.

Instead of built in spark functions ..you can use plain scala code to get same result.

```
val df = spark.sql("select * from your_table")

def date_concat(date:Column): Column = { 
    concat(substring(date,4,2),year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date,"dd-MM-yyyy")))))
}

df.withColumn("date_column_name",date_concat($"date_column_name")) // with function.
df.withColumn("date_column_name",concat(substring($"date_column_name",4,2),year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"date_column_name","dd-MM-yyyy")))))) // without function, direct method.
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table_name")
spark.sql("[...]") // Write your furthur logic in sql if you want.
```

Comment: Hi @Srinivas can you guide me or give me some hint please.I'm new to scala using UDF first time I've created one methods in scala def date_concat(idt:Column): Column = {
  val a1=concat(substring(idt,4,2),year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(idt,"dd-MM-yyyy")))))
  a1
  
    } and using this methods name in sparksql query and passing table column name as parameter.But its not working for me

Comment: Simple way is to use DF without spark.sql and convert all the required dates and create temporary table and use like  normal SQL queries.

Comment: Morning I have answered same question .

Comment: I have updated code in the answer, You can do something like without UDF.

Comment: As per your question its not possible to use functions inside UDF, updated answer for  workaround .. please let me know if not working ..